# sendFile absolute path

Tags: node.js, express

On Windows machine, I have a **mapped** share folder => Z:/uploads/

using express, I use res.senFile to return a file to the browser:

```
var download = config.file_dir + "/" + file;
res.sendFile(download);
```

download value is `Z:/uploads/737237213791239.pdf`

I get this error:

```
throw new TypeError('path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile
```

Am I giving a absolute path?

Comment: Possibly it doesn't like the fact you've mapped it (or that Windows drive path's don't look nice) as mapped drives are limited to the session you map them in. I'd try firstly using Windows style backslashes "\" or secondly a UNC path. "\\machinename\share\path\file.ext"

Comment: I think you are right.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue. I found it easiest to configure my folder with forward slashes, the use path.join to send. This should work work a drive letter or UNC path.

```
var path = require("path");
config.file_dir = "z:/folder";
//use forward slashes for UNC if you wish to use that instead ie //server/share

var file = path.join(config.file_dir, urlPath);

res.sendFile(file, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        res.status(err.status || 500).send();
    }
 });
```